# Optimize Database Search Query

Tags: java, mysql, sql, sql-server, jdbc

I have table that has following columns
-> `col1, col2, col3`

I am trying to search using these columns. So I am taking the 3 inputs from user.

***Simple rules for search:***

1) If any-of `col` is NOT entered by user then it should search using only other 2 columns.

```
select * from myTable where col1="abc" and col2="def"; // something like this. Any combination like col1-col2, col1-col3 or col2-col3
```

2) If all `col`s are entered then:

```
select * from myTable where col1="abc" and col2="def" and col3="ghi"; // something like this
```

3) If any-of one `col` is entered by user then:

```
select * from myTable where col1="abc"; // something like this. It can be col1, col2 or col3.
```

I know this can be DONE by using different `select` statements for database and using `if-else` in Java code.

I want a **MOST OPTIMIZED** solution (with little code/explanation) for this situation.

**EDIT**

**NOTE:** All 3 columns are **NULL**-able !! I am using **Microsoft-SQL Server** (MSSQL) but I want solution for both, MySQL and MSSQL

Comment: What ORM are you using, btw query will always be created after your if else statements, so will be optimized.

Comment: @ankur-singhal just want a simple sql query. Most Optimized solution.

Comment: You can do that with a loop contain the where clause, and then use that where with single selection.

Comment: You tagged this with `mysql` **and** `mssql` (Microsoft SQL Server). What are you really using?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name `mssql` ... but I want the solution for both database.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I have updated my question. Please have a look. Thanks

Comment: The most optimsed solution *will* be to have six separate queries - one for each combination of populated parameters, and call the right one each time.  Anything else involves RDBMS overhead of one sort or another.

Comment: @MichaelGreen There are 8 combination, not 6.

Comment: @rtruszk C1,C2,C3,C1C2,C1C3,C2C3,C1C2C3 = 7 combinations.  Fair enough, not 6.  I read the question as no possibility of all-NULL.

Comment: @MichaelGreen Having 7 separate queries moves optimization from DBMS to application. But optimization of such simple query is easy and fast task for DBMS.

Comment: @rtruszk, I guess my experience is different to yours.  With stale statistics, skewed cardinalities, disjunctions and NULLable columns to deal with, I've seen the optimizer produce awful plans for such short SQL.  The question asked for an optimized solution.  I took this to mean one with the shortest elapsed time.  I hold to my original statement - the shortest elapsed time wil be reliably obtained by statements without NULLs, using AND only, avoiding ORs.

Comment: I just need **one optimized** query that cater everything !! Else I know that this can be easily DONE by `if-else` but I don't want `if-else`in my application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you're binding variables named `:col1`, `:col2` and `:col3`, respectively, this can be done in a single statement by using a couple of `or` conditions. The idea here is to have the database perform a short circuit logic for eahc column - if the user passes null that part of the condition is just evaluated to `true`, without accessing the table. If a real value if passed, it's compared to the column in the table.

```
SELECT *
FROM   myTable 
WHERE  (:col1 IS NULL OR :col1 = '' OR :col1 = col1) AND
       (:col2 IS NULL OR :col2 = '' OR :col2 = col2) AND
       (:col3 IS NULL OR :col3 = '' OR :col3 = col3)
```

Comment: Well I have 3 questions in your answer. 1) Is there a way to in SQL query that check the value I am passing is `NULL` or not, please give a reference? 2) What if I have `:col1 = ""` and I donot want to consider it in my search statement. 3) And what does this means `:col1 IS NULL OR col1=:col1` (in words)?

Comment: @Junaid 1) That's exactly what my query does :-) 2) I didn't notice you were asking about MySQL, which treats empty strings differently from `null`s - I edited the question accordingly. 3) I edited the answer in an attempt to clarify.

Comment: Well your query seems very interesting and logical. While testing your query I come across with this problem ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28177447/send-multiple-type-parameters-spring-mybatis-query ). Can you please help me. Thanks

Comment: Interesting I use a slightly different version

Answer (score 3):

Surely this is all you need?

```
Select * 
    from myTable 
where (col1 like @col1 +'%' or @col1 is null) 
  and (col2 like @col2 +'%' or @col2 is null) 
  and (col3 like @col3 +'%' or @col3 is null)
```

Comment: LIKE statement with the following wildcard pattern `%someterm%` cannot use indexes and thus will always be dog slow. The only way a LIKE statement can use an index is by using the following wildcard pattern `someterm%`

Comment: Can you please explain why don't you write `( @col1 is null or col1 like @col1 +'%') ` ... Should it check for `null` first ??

Comment: It doesn't make a difference as far as I'm aware as it will evaluate both expressions anyway. That being said I am aware that some DBMS's can be set to stop evaluating or's after it finds one that returns true. If that was the case you'd be best to set whichever is most likely to return true first in the statement.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use nested `CASE` in your query. Then query conditions would be simpler when some of variables are `null`.

First proposition:

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable 
WHERE
  CASE
    WHEN @col1 is NULL OR @col1 = '' THEN 
      CASE 
        WHEN @col2 is NULL OR @col2 = '' THEN
          CASE 
            WHEN @col3 is NULL OR @col3 = '' THEN 1=1
            ELSE @col3 = col3
          END
        ELSE
          CASE 
            WHEN @col3 is NULL OR @col3 = '' THEN @col2 = col2
            ELSE @col2 = col2 AND @col3 = col3
          END
      END
    ELSE
      CASE 
        WHEN @col2 is NULL OR @col2 = '' THEN
          CASE 
            WHEN @col3 is NULL OR @col3 = '' THEN @col1 = col1
            ELSE @col1 = col1 AND @col3 = col3
          END
        ELSE
          CASE 
            WHEN @col3 is NULL OR @col3 = '' THEN @col1 = col1 AND @col2 = col2
            ELSE @col1 = col1 AND @col2 = col2 AND @col3 = col3
          END
      END
  END;
```

And second proposition:

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable 
WHERE
  col1 = 
  CASE
    WHEN @col1 IS NULL OR @col1 = '' THEN col1
    ELSE @col1
  END
AND
  col2 = 
  CASE
    WHEN @col2 IS NULL OR @col2= '' THEN col2
    ELSE @col2
  END
AND
  col3 = 
  CASE
    WHEN @col3 IS NULL OR @col3= '' THEN col3
    ELSE @col3
  END;
```

You can see the result in [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e0bc77/18)

**EDIT:**

So there are three different queries. One is proposed by Mureinik and two above proposed by me. To decide which one of them is optimal we have to be avare of how MySQL (and other DBMS's) optimizes query before execution. We can see details [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/where-optimizations.html).

The most important phrase for us is

> Constant condition removal

It means that condition `(1=1)` from one of my queries will be removed. It also means than when `:col1` and `:col2` are both nulls and `:col3 = 'aaa'` then Mureinik's query:

```
WHERE  (NULL  IS NULL OR NULL  = '' OR NULL  = col1) AND
   (NULL  IS NULL OR NULL  = '' OR NULL  = col2) AND
   ('aaa' IS NULL OR 'aaa' = '' OR 'aaa' = col3)
```

will be simplified to:

```
WHERE 'aaa' = col3
```

If we analyze all 3 proposed queries this way we will see that for every set of variables `col1`, `col2` and `col3` all these queries will be optimized by DBMS to exactly the same query. So all three of them are equally performant. So you can choose whichever you want (Mureinik's one seems the clearest one)

Comment: You have 3 search quires in SQLFiddle right? Which one most Optimized and why ? And these quires gonna run on MSSQL too ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that as below using PHP, do the same way with Java:

```
$mapColVal = array( 1 => $first_post_value, 2 => $second_post_value, 3 => $third_post_value);
$whereCond = '';
for($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++){
   $whereCond .= "col".$i. "=". $mapColValue[$i]." AND ";
}
$whereCond = subStr($whereCond,0,-5);
```

Then do as bellow:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE $whereCond;
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be very easily done using a case in the where clause:

```
SET @col1='someterm1';
SET @col2='someterm2';
SET @col3=NULL;

SELECT  *
FROM table tbl1
WHERE 
    CASE WHEN @col1 IS NULL THEN 1=1 ELSE tbl1.col1=@col1 END
    AND CASE WHEN @col2 IS NULL THEN 1=1 ELSE tbl1.col2=@col2 END
    AND CASE WHEN @col3 IS NULL THEN 1=1 ELSE tbl1.col3=@col3 END;
```

The where clause will only search for a value if you pass a NON-NULL value. So the above statement will look like follows when the variables/paramaters are substituted:

```
SELECT  *
FROM table tbl1
WHERE 
    CASE WHEN @col1 IS NULL THEN 1=1 ELSE tbl1.col1='someterm1' END
    AND CASE WHEN @col2 IS NULL THEN 1=1 ELSE tbl1.col2='someterm2' END
    /* THIS LINE AND CASE WHEN @col3 IS NULL THEN 1=1 ELSE tbl1.col3=@col3 END; changes because of the NULL*/
   AND 1=1;
```

Thus you can pass any combination of fields that you hav and only those fields will be searched.For the fields you dont have send a NULL value and the CASE statement turns that into a 1=1 and the criteria is not applied.

The technique should work on any database engine.

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that the names of your columns are not exactly col1, col2, col3, and that the number of columns may expand in the future, so you want something that will not need to be completely reworked when that happens. You will therefore need to have an array that holds the column names. The user input should likewise be from a list of Strings with the same size as the array of column names.

I will also assume that you are using a prepared statement of some sort, but if not, just follow the basic outline.

Additionally, my assumption is that if all inputs are null we will return the entire table.

```
private final String[] COLUMNS = new String[]{"col1", "col2", "col3"};

public static PreparedStatement getStatement(String queryString){
   //you do this
}

public static PreparedStatement generateOptimizedStatement(List<String> input) {
  String whereOrAnd = " where ";
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("select * from myTable ");
  int i = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i < COLUMNS.length; i++){
    if(input.get(i) != null){
      sb.append(whereOrAnd).append(COLUMNS[i]).append(" = ? ");
      whereOrAnd = " and ";  
    }
  }
  PreparedStatement ps = getStatement(sb);
  for(int j = 0; j < COLUMNS.length; j++){
    String s = input.get(j);
    if(s != null){
      ps.setString(j+ 1, s); //prepared statement starts with index 1
    }
  }
  return ps;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

One point you should note is that in a WHERE clause, adding an "OR" usually adds a lot of overhead to a query. An "AND" is usually much faster and requires less computing by the compiler. So I would try something that would not use that as best as possible.

Here is my idea of how to best optimize this:

1) put indexes on all 3 columns (col1, col2, col3).
2) Determining which columns to be used should, ideally, be computed in Java and based on this the query would be fired. Here is my idea (in PHP, but can be extended to Java... Sorry, not familiar enough!):

```
<?php

if (isset($_GET['options'])) {
$options = explode(",",$_GET['options']); // assuming you feed the columns separated with columns
}

if (isset($_GET['col1Value'])) {
$col1Value = $_GET['col1Value']; 
}

if (isset($_GET['col2Value'])) {
$col2Value = $_GET['col2Value']; 
}

if (isset($_GET['col3Value'])) {
$col3Value = $_GET['col3Value']; 
}

if (in_array("col1",$options)) { // check to see if 'col1' exists in array
$clause = ' and coalesce(col1,'') = $col1Value';
}

if (in_array("col2",$options)) { // check to see if 'col2' exists in array
$clause = $clause.' and coalesce(col2,'') = $col2Value';
}

if (in_array("col3",$options)) { // check to see if 'col3' exists in array
$clause = $clause.' and coalesce(col3,'') = $col3Value';
}


$sql = "

select *
from table
where 1=1
     $clause
";

pg_execute($databaseConnection,$sql);

?>
```

This is probably not the best example as it is in PHP, but hopefully that gives you some ideas....

Cheers!